# Drupal 7 Install Error

Tags: drupal, installation, drupal-7

I was hoping that someone can shed some light on why I am getting this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /homepages/22/d223624283/htdocs/drupal_new/includes/install.core.inc  on line 74

Could it be something that I missed?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you got a snapshot with broken files. Try the official latest alpha from http://drupal.org/project/drupal

Comment: You know what it was I needed to add to my .htaccess file

AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

Then I was able to see the pages render... I also was not able to save my DB as MySQL I had to save the DB as SQlite.

I kept getting an error about permissions and hostname when trying to save DB as MySQL.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Yup. Adding the AddType line to the .htaccess file is the solution for me too. And this is with the Drupal 7.0 release.